# .htaccess rules to have cakephp in root and core php in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have an cakephp application as the root folder and `.htaccess` is written as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now what I want is a core php application in its Subfolder, but `.htaccess` is causing trouble for me.
What is best way to write the `.htaccess` so both can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply put whatever it is you want to access in the webroot directory i.e. for the url `http://example.com/other/thing.php` don't do this:

```
html/
    app
        webroot/
    other/
         thing.php
```

Do this:

```
html/
    app
        webroot/
            other/
                thing.php
```